# samba setup for simple NAS - is it as secure as it could be?

Tags: linux, security, debian, samba

I'm setting up a music server for my family. It is actually working, which is why I'm on (was on code review, bounced off as not really code) here. I'm not happy that I understand enough about how samba is configured, to understand the security considerations of the options I have finally arrived at in my smb.conf file. I am not security paranoid as such, but as I do access my bank from machines on the network, I don't want to hang a big sign outside my house saying 'please hack'. I have looked at howtogeek and samba.org, and the examples they gave did not seem to fit exactly, or work as they said they should. The .conf file has been arrived at with some poking, and guessing from the full samba reference.

Anyhow, first the requirements. I have a raspberry PI, with a number of FAT32 USB sticks plugged in as mass storage. I would prefer to keep FAT32 for convenient compatibility with the MS machines in the house. If I have to format as extn, I'll think about that. I want any number of users to have simultaneous readonly access to the files, and one admin user to have write access over the network (as well as ssh). I am running the ubiquitous debian wheezy on the PI. I am a linux noob, but slowly being dragged up the learning curve.

What's working

I now have write access to all the sticks from my admin user, and can get simulataneous access for three users all logged in as the same user from a chromebook, a Mint PC, and an XP PC, and they were refused write access on permissions. So the base functionality I'm after does seem to be working. I'm happy for the users to need to login rather than just connect as guest.

To get that functionality, have I created any silly vulnerabilities?

I am not too sure what the samba model is. Can you confirm that each [resource] section defines the behaviour that a user will get when they log in to that resource. This should mean that the different resource blocks can specify the same path =, without conflict. I've not seen this actually spelled out for samba, but it seems to me it has to work that way. This is why I have different settings for readonly in the user and admin resources, and it seems to work OK.

I have set fstab to mount the sticks under /media, and this is the folder that samba shares. I at first tried to chown everything to my admin user, but this didn't work. On searching, I found that  the FAT format doesn't support ownership, which sounded like the reason. Everything returned root for owner by default, and one of the examples on samba.org used the force user root line, and it seems to work now. This however is the option I'm least happy with.

This is the smb.conf file, I've stripped out most of the comments and most of the inactive options from the example file that came with the installation 3.6.6.

```
# This will prevent nmbd to search for NetBIOS names through DNS.
   dns proxy = no

# This tells Samba to use a separate log file for each machine
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

# Cap the size of the individual log files (in KiB).
   max log size = 1000

   syslog = 0

# Do something sensible when Samba crashes: mail the admin a backtrace
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   security = user
   encrypt passwords = true
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n        *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes

   map to guest = bad user

#======================= Share Definitions =======================
[Library]
comment = Music Library
path = /media
read only = yes
browsable = yes

[Lib_Admin]
comment = Lib Admin
path = /media
valid users = admin_lib
force user = root
create mask = 0744
directory mask = 0755
browsable = yes
read only = no
```

The main questions are ...
a) is the security reasonable on this?
b) are there better options for doing what I am trying to do?

I think I should take map to guest out
should I put root dir = /media, with the mirroring of files to /media that will be necessary?